# what are some good resources for QGD exchanged where black plays Nh5 and later Nb6 Be6 and 0-0-0

Tags: opening, strategy, queens-gambit, queens-gambit-declined

Here is a different approach of playing the QGD as black. A general idea after Qxe7 is to play **Nb6**, **Be6** followed by **0-0-0**. I don't know if this variation has a name but Nh5 seems to be popular and has a good score for black compared to 0-0 according to the Lichess masters database.

Are there any good resources where I can learn this variation.

```
       [FEN ""]
       [White ""]
       [Black ""]


       1. d4 d5 2. c4 e6 3. Nc3 Nf6 4. Bg5 Be7 5. cxd5 exd5 6. e3 c6 7. Bd3 Nbd7 8. Qc2 Nh5 9. Bxe7 Qxe7
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't provide sources about the theory other than exploring master games from a database, but as a general strategic theme it's good to learn about the Karlsbad pawn structure to learn some long-term plans.

White will usually try to play on the queenside, , trying to get something out of the semi-open "c" file by breaking Black's pawn structure with a b4-b5 push, but first they will try to get their king into safety: Nf3 (Ne2!?) and 0-0 are coming soon.

Black usually tries to anticipate White's plan by creating bigger threats on the center and kingside. As the knight is placed on h5, Black may try their chance to go ...f5-f4 earlier than usual. On the other hand, the lack of a dark-squared bishop makes attacking harder.

Comment: what ive realized is this is more solid and black has some plans of g6 Ng7 and Bf5 exchanging the lsb as well. but haven't look into much

Comment: @cmgchess you could be right. The lack of the dark-squared bishop could make Black's attack nearly impossible thus forcing them into more positional plans. Hard to say so early on without specific master games to reference.

Comment: i found [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sZMnd9oSpa0) video and he starts to speak a little about this around 4 minute mark. but nothing much